# std::set with unconsistent operator<

Tags: c++, set, stdset

I'm writing a C++ algorithm to solve a board game.
The solution is based on the following:

```
enqueue initial board
while queue not empty:
    dequeue a board
    if board is solved:
        print solution
    else:
        for each possible board that can arise out of this one:
            add board to end of queue
```

Since I don't want to examine the same board more than one time I use `std::set<Board>` to keep track of examined boards.

In `Board` class `bool operator<(const Board& rhs) const` is defined to make `std::set` work properly.

So what happens in my `std::set` if my comparison function doesn't ensure an order in board instances?

As example:

```
a = Board()
b = Board()
c = Board()

a > b returns true
b > c returns true
a > c returns false
```

Is it possible that `std::set`, since it's based on *Red-Black Tree*, inserts the same Board more than once?

Comment: if `operator<` does not work as proper comparator - container behavior is undefined and implementation specific

Comment: Since the program would be undefined, anything could happen.

Comment: To add to what others have stated, if you're using Visual C++, the debug runtime checks this and will fail with an assert() if you did anything like what you've posted.  So for the Visual C++ debug runtime, the behavior is "well-defined" -- your program will `assert()` and exit.

Comment: I can't get what is checked and when from your answer. You mean an assert is thrown in `std:set insert`?

Comment: @kuket15: Correct, VC++ asserts when inserting an element that is unordered with respect to the items with which it's compared. Keep in mind that Visual C++ won't compare it with _all_ set elements, that would be prohibitively expensive even for debug builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the comparator doesn't work properly, the structure won't work properly. It might report that items are missing. It might fail to insert something. It could crash quickly, or it could appear to work for all your test cases and then crash on the customer's machine.

All bets are off.

Comment: Can you serialize boards, i.e. turn them into a string or sequence of bytes? If so, you can compare the serialized representations. (This does require a unique serialization; i.e. if a particular serialization depends on the history of moves then two "identical" board may in fact be unequal. C++ doesn't make assumptions here)